# Making a Apple Wiki Server resolve to a Domain Name

Tags: domain-name, apple

I have a wiki at `https://server.companydomain.com/groups/wiki` but I'd like people to access the wiki via `https://www.newdomain.com`

Is it possible to have this domain resolve to the wiki?  I don't really want people access it via /groups/wiki

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a redirect page at "https://www.newdomain.com" which will then steer them over to "https://server.companydomain.com/groups/wiki" or even from "http://www.newdomain.com" and not have to deal with the additional SSL certificate.